# Specify Input File in SPSS Statistics

Tags: python, vba, spss

In older versions of SPSS, one could ask for the path to a file using a syntax similar to this:

```
filename = GetFilePath("*.txt","txt", ,"Specify input file",0)
```

How can I achieve the same result using recent versions of SPSS, that rely on Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. So similarly to how the VBA in `.SBS` script works, Python can use a library directly from SPSS to show a file input dialog.

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: That works, but using the CDB would give you a dialog that looks like the standard Statistics dialogs and could include more than just the Browse window.  Also, be aware that some older versions of Statistics did not work well with repeated use of Tkinter in the same session.  (Tkinter and the Viewer would fight over the message queue.)  Fixed in V22 or 23, I think.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @JKP . I am targeting V24 and future versions. At the same time I want to minimize and isolate the use of SPSS specific functionality. The project is for internal use and we have fewer and fewer SPSS expertise available.

Comment: okay.  Good luck.  You might still find the CDB useful in preparing targeted interfaces for users who might not know much about SPSS Statistics.

Answer (score 1):

sbs/wwd scripts are still supported on Statistics.

As for the prompt, you could create a wwd/sbs dialog to prompt for the file name and then open it, or, without using scripting, you could create a custom dialog box using the Custom Dialog Builder (on Utilities) containing a Browse control and issue a GET command.

If you want this to happen when Statistics is launched, you can create a startup script or use the STATS PROJECT extension command, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of SPSS Statistics ever having a function such as GetFilePath, but you can use the Python spssaux.getDatasetInfo function for this, e.g., in a program write

import spssaux
filename = spssaux.getDatasetInfo()

Comment: This specific piece of functionality, which I am referring to,is part of a .SBS script, which cannot run on current versions of SPSS.

Comment: The question is about how you can interactively ask the user for an input path, not for how you can retrieve the path of an already loaded file.